# Number input field exclude range of numbers in middle

Tags: javascript, html, input, attributes

In input field how can i exclude range of numbers

e.g. allow user to put `value < -5` or `value > 5` and not allow anything between -4 to 4?. I am not asking for `max` or `min` values

```
<input type="number" id="input" step="1" />
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First add excmin and excmax attribute to target element(in this case element with id="input") to values you want.
Then call this function and pass element to this function on page load:

:

```
function exceptionrange(element)
{
 var excmin=parseInt(element.getAttribute("excmin"))-1;
 var excmax=parseInt(element.getAttribute("excmax"))+1;
 element.onchange=function()
 {
  if(element.value<excmax&&element.value>excmin)
  {
   element.value=Math.round((parseInt(element.value)-excmin)/(excmin-excmax))*(excmin-excmax)+excmin;
  }
 };
}
```

Now, whenever user enter a value in this range, it will change it to near allowed value when user is done entering number. 
So this is how script will look like:

```
function exceptionrange(element)
{
 var excmin=parseInt(element.getAttribute("excmin"))-1;
 var excmax=parseInt(element.getAttribute("excmax"))+1;
 element.onchange=function()
 {
  if(element.value<excmax&&element.value>excmin)
  {
   element.value=Math.round((parseInt(element.value)-excmin)/(excmin-excmax))*(excmin-excmax)+excmin;
  }
 };
}
window.addEventListener("load",function()
{
 var input=document.getElementById("input");
 exceptionrange(input);
});
```

And this is the input element:

```
<input type="number" id="input" step="1" excmin="-4" excmax="4"/>
```

Comment: `excmin` and `excmax` are not native attributes right? working fiddle for anyone interested https://jsfiddle.net/ck66nvmv/

Comment: Right, they are not native attributes, they are used in javascript function exceptionrange

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to exclude 2,4,5,7,8,9,10,11 from my Shopify products quantity in input number field so I created the following code for it.

Input Element

```
<input type="number" id="input"/>
```

JS code

```
function exceptionrange(element)
{
 var inputValue = 0
 element.onchange=function()
 {
  if(inputValue<element.value){
    if(element.value==2)
    {
     element.value=3;
    }
    if(element.value==4 || element.value==5)
    {
     element.value=6;
    }
    if(element.value==7 || element.value==8 || element.value==9 || element.value==10 || element.value==11)
    {
     element.value= 12;
    }
  }
  if(inputValue>element.value){
    if(element.value==2)
    {
     element.value=1;
    }
    if(element.value==4 || element.value==5)
    {
     element.value=3;
    }
    if(element.value==7 || element.value==8 || element.value==9 || element.value==10 || element.value==11)
    {
     element.value= 6;
    }
  }
  inputValue = element.value
 };
}
window.addEventListener("load",function()
{
 var input=document.getElementById("input");
 exceptionrange(input);
});
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked perfectly.